How can I mark a nuget package on artifactory as deprecated
we are using Jfrog Artifactory for hosting internal nuget packages for our internal developer community.
I would need to know, if there is some way to mark a local hosted nugetpackage as deprecated, so that developers consuming this package are informed to upgrade to a different package on Visual Studio.
Nuget Package on Artifactory should be marked as deprecated, like on nuget.org

